# Facebook login warning issue on admin account

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app on developers.facebook.com. I am the app admin. There is no other admin. The app has an associated fb login button on a personal web app. The login button has 3 permissions in scope.

```
public_profile,email,pages_show_list
```

When I am testing the login button using the app admin account, I am getting a warning on the login popup.

```
Submit for Login Review
Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook.
Submit for review now or learn more.
```

As I am app admin and I am supposed to have standard access for the mentioned permissions, why am I getting the warning? I intend to use the app with my personal fb assets. It will not be released for the public. What can I do to make the warning go away?

Comment: _“What can I do to make the warning go away?”_ - submit your app for review. Or live with it, if all the functionality you want to implement works without submitting.